# PyCaret and Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, pycaret

I try to use PyCaret in a Google Cloud Function but I cannot import the classification modules (from pycaret.classification import *) because there is a reference to a non writable directory (OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/workspace/logs.log') Does anybody know a workaround or does that mean that PyCaret is not compliant with Cloud Function yet ?

Comment: Hi vmady, welcome! In order to make your question clearer, could you please add the whole or part of your code so that it is easier for reviewers to help you? Don't forget to format it properly. Thank you

Comment: It is not in my code, the error occurs during the importation of the pycaret module. The problem has been identified by the pycaret team and will be fixed in the coming releases : https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/998

Answer (score 0):

The PyCaret team has fixed the problem in the current nigthly builds of the module and it is now working fine with Cloud Functions. Thank you guys :)